# Get user to set role ID

Tags: discord, discord.js

Im trying to setup a system where the user can change the role ID for staff but every time i restart my bot the ID resets back. Here is my code:

this is estaff.js

```
const roles = require("./roles");

module.exports = {
  name: "estaff",
  callback: ({ message, args }) => {
    if (args.length === 0)
      message.channel.send(`Current estaff role is <@&${roles.EstaffRole}>`);
    else {
      roles.EstaffRole = args[0];
      message.channel.send("Successfully changed estaff role");
    }
  },
};
```

this is the roles.js file:

```
const roles = {
  HstaffRole: "956109121550168114",
  GstaffRole: "956112990116134953",
  EstaffRole: "932558453203943434",
};

module.exports = roles;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are misunderstanding how data is stored in this case.

This is not permanent storage, for a problem like this then you would require a database/storing system.

To help you understand, what you currently are doing is:

```
const roles = require("./roles");
```

This will get you a reference to the array in roles.js.

Assuming the call has the necessary arguments, you then

```
roles.EstaffRole = args[0];
```

This is going to change the array in roles, but not the files in roles.js.

Perhaps you could run this while looking at your roles.js and realise that you are not really changing anything, it will only work as long as your server/program is running.

Comment: oh yeah, makes sense. totally forgot about that. Thanks man. So i should just use a database eh

Comment: Yeah, just any database would work. If this is not important/you just want proof of storing, then maybe even a text file.

If you want to explore/try new things, you could try MongoDB